# struggling with css and formatting my website

Tags: html, css

i want to decorate my website and add a few images of egyption gods with a button below them, so when you click on the button that says the name of the god, their descriptions will be displayed. I also want to toggle the themes of my website where by clicking the toggle them button, my whole enter website theme will changed

im kinda strugging with css and whatever background colour im setting it too, the website is not changing so any help with that would be appreciated <3.

here is my base code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sriLq.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about the [best way to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to provide a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your post to meet the guidelines. Sharing your HTML and CSS code as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) will make it a lot easier for the community to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Not much to go on with the code however I could give some advice on how I would go about doing it. I would go about implementing this:

```
 <div>
    <img src='image.png'>
    <p class='hidden'> this is the description </p>
    <button>Show/Hide description </button> 
 </div>
```

You will have each image with its own description and button in a div and the description will be hidden by default. Add a event listener to the button so onclick it will add/remove the hidden class to show/hide the description.